# mystery Error #1063: Argument count mismatch

Tags: actionscript

So I'm getting a "Error #1063: Argument count mismatch" error.  The weird thing is that it isn't keeping the game from running, but I would like to know why I'm even getting an error in the first place.  The full error is:

```
ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on Hock(). Expected 3, got 0.
    at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()
    at flash.display::Sprite()
    at flash.display::MovieClip()
    at PlayScreen()[Z:\PROJECTS\Silversound\Occulus Squish\Oculus Squish\Classes\PlayScreen.as:30]
    at Main/addPlayscreen()[Z:\PROJECTS\Silversound\Occulus Squish\Oculus Squish\Classes\Main.as:17]
    at Main()[Z:\PROJECTS\Silversound\Occulus Squish\Oculus Squish\Classes\Main.as:13]
    at runtime::ContentPlayer/loadInitialContent()
    at runtime::ContentPlayer/playRawContent()
    at runtime::ContentPlayer/playContent()
    at runtime::AppRunner/run()
    at ADLAppEntry/run()
    at global/runtime::ADLEntry()
```

The Code for PlayScreen is:

```
import flashx.textLayout.formats.BackgroundColor;
import flash.display.SimpleButton;
import flash.ui.Mouse;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;

public class PlayScreen extends MovieClip
{

    public var batArmy:Array;
    public var hockArmy:Array;
    public var shadow:Shadow;
    public var crossHairs:CrossHairs;
    var Layer01:MovieClip;
    var Layer02:MovieClip;
    var Layer03:MovieClip; 
    var Layer04:MovieClip;
    var Layer05:MovieClip;
    var randomX:Number = 300 + (660 - 300) * Math.random();

    public function PlayScreen() 
    {
        //Mouse.hide();
        addBatButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addBat);
        addHockButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addHock);
        batArmy = new Array();
        hockArmy = new Array();
        //addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, crossHairsMove);
        //stage.addEventListener( KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyPress );

        Layer01 = new MovieClip;
        this.addChild(Layer01);
        Layer02 = new MovieClip;
        this.addChild(Layer02);
        Layer03 = new MovieClip;
        this.addChild(Layer03);
        Layer04 = new MovieClip;
        this.addChild(Layer04);
        Layer05 = new MovieClip;
        this.addChild(Layer05);


        //add crossHair


        /*crossHairs = new CrossHairs(mouseX,mouseY,this);
        Layer05.addChild (crossHairs);
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, crossHairsMove);*/


    }
    /*public function onKeyPress( keyboardEvent:KeyboardEvent ):void
    {
        if ( keyboardEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN )
        {
            trace("yar");
            addBat;
        }
    }*/
    public function addBat( mouseEvent:MouseEvent ):void
    {
        var randomX:Number = 300 + (660 - 300) * Math.random();
        var newBat = new Bat( randomX, -50, this);
        batArmy.push ( newBat );
        Layer02.addChild (newBat);
    }
    public function addHock( mouseEvent:MouseEvent ):void
    {
        var newHock = new Hock(-72, 170, this);
        hockArmy.push ( newHock );
        Layer02.addChild (newHock);
    }
    /*public function crossHairsMove ( e:Event ):void
    {
        crossHairs.x = mouseX;
        crossHairs.y = mouseY;
    }*/
}
```

and from the looks of it the error has something to do with the Hock class, so here's the code for that:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.ui.Mouse;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.events.Event;

public class Hock extends MovieClip
{
    private var _screen: PlayScreen;
    public var xSpeed:Number;

    public function Hock( startX:Number, startY:Number, screen:PlayScreen ) 
    {
        _screen = screen;
        x = startX;
        y = startY;
        width = 100;
        scaleY = scaleX;
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveRightFar);
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveSpeed)
    }
    public function moveSpeed( e:Event ):void
    {
        x += xSpeed;
    }
    public function moveRightFar ( e:Event): void
    {
        if (x < 0)
        {
            gotoAndStop("rollRight");
            xSpeed = 13;
        }
        else if (x >= 240)
        {
            gotoAndStop("still")
            xSpeed = 0;
        }
    }

}
```

Now I could be wrong but I think it's having a problem with `var newHock = new Hock(-72, 170, this);` in the "addHock" function, but I have 3 arguments there, not 0.  Right?  Anyway, like I said, it's not keeping the game from running but it is kind of annoying, so any insight is welcome.  I'm sure it's something obvious.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have a guess, but I'll explain how i got there first ...

the first line of the stacktrace pointing at your source code is
`at PlayScreen()[Z:\PROJECTS\Silversound\Occulus Squish\Oculus Squish\Classes\PlayScreen.as:30]`
which points at the first line of the constructor of PlayScreen: `addBatButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addBat);`
but obviously the problem is not there ...

But **PlayScreen** extends **MovieClip** and since you didn't specifically included a **super()** statement, the compiler will put that at as the first command. In fact, the previous lines of the stack point to the constructor of **MovieClip** and then to a mysterious `constructChildren()` method of **Sprite**

That happens to be an internal method used to create the childs of the **Sprite** that you might have setup on your clip's stage directly from Animate.

So my guess is, the player is trying to instantiate a symbol that extends **Hock** and that you positioned on the stage somewhere, and of course is doing it by passing zero arguments because that's what a normal **Sprite** would expect.

Check your library to see what extends **Hock** and then see which one of those is placed in some other symbol's stage. Your options then will be to remove that and create it from code or to rework the class signature to take zero arguments.